# What does 'component $i_n$' mean here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

I am wondering what $\pi_0P^n(i_n)$ means with the 'component $i_n$'- what in the matrix $\pi_0P^n$ are we accessing with this $(i_n)$? What is the 'component $i_n$'- a certain row of the matrix?

For context, I am ignorant of linear algebra and have just been learning about Markov Chains, but my research online hasn't resolved this issue.
Here is the area where I have encountered this notation (the specific part I am asking about is at the bottom):

> One defines a general finite Markov chain as follows. The state space is $\mathscr{X}=\{1,2, \ldots, K\}$ for some finite $K$. The transition probability matrix $P$ is a $K \times K$ matrix such that
> $$
> P(i, j) \geq 0, \forall i, j \in \mathscr{X}
> $$
> and
> $$
> \sum_{j=1}^K P(i, j)=1, \forall i \in \mathscr{X}$$The initial distribution is a vector $\pi_0=${$ \pi_0(i), i \in \mathscr{X}$} where $\pi_0(i) \geq 0$ for all $i \in \mathscr{X}$ and $\sum_{i \in \mathscr{X}} \pi_0(i)=1$. One then defines the random sequence {$X_n, n=0,1,2, \ldots$} by
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_0=i\right]=\pi_0(i), i \in \mathscr{X} \\
> & \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_{n+1}=j \mid X_n=i, X_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0\right]=P(i, j), \forall n \geq 0, \forall i, j \in \mathscr{X} .
> \end{aligned}$$Note that
> $$
> \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_0=i_0, X_1=i_1, \ldots, X_n=i_n\right]
> $$
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & =\operatorname{Pr}\left[X_0=i_0\right] \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_1=i_1 \mid X_0=i_0\right] \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_2=i_2 \mid X_0=i_0, X_1=i_1\right] \cdots \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_n=i_n \mid X_0=i_0, \ldots, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\right] \\
> & =\pi_0\left(i_0\right) P\left(i_0, i_1\right) \cdots P\left(i_{n-1}, i_n\right) .
> \end{aligned}$$Consequently,
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \operatorname{Pr} & {\left[X_n=i_n\right]=\sum_{i_0, \ldots i_{n-1}} \operatorname{Pr}\left[X_0=i_0, X_1=i_1, \ldots, X_n=i_n\right] } \\
> & =\sum_{i_0, \ldots i_{n-1}} \pi_0\left(i_0\right) P\left(i_0, i_1\right) \cdots P\left(i_{n-1}, i_n\right) \\
> & =\pi_0 P^n\left(i_n\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where the last expression is component $i_n$ of the product of the row vector $\pi_0$ times the $n$-th power of the matrix $P$.

Comment: The $i_n$-th coordinate in the vector $\pi_0 P^n$.

Comment: Note that multiplying a row vector with a matrix gives a row vector.